# how to include two separate layouts in one layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

i have a layout titled "status2.xml" and its code is posted below. and i have a main layout titled "meine_vertaege.xml" and its code is posted below as well. the "act_main.xml" includes the aforementioned layouts, 
which are namely "status2.xml" and "meine_vertaege.xml".

I am including "status2.xml" and "meine_vertaege" in the "act_main.xml" as shown below in the code of the "act_main.xml".

the problem i have is when i include both of "status2.xml" and meine_vertaege" in the "act_main.xml", i cant see the entire contents of the "status2.xml" because it seems that the contents of "status2.xml" and "meine_vertaege.xml"
got mixed up

please let me know how to include both of "status2.xml" and "meine_vertaege" in "act_main.xml" so that i can see their entire contents in such way that they are organized vertically

**status2.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Status"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="vertraege"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**output of status2.xml**:

[image]

**meine_vertaege.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/actMain_meine_vertraege_layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
    android:text="Meine Verträge" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/actMain_lisVie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**output of meine_vertaege.xml**:

[image]

**act_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.bestandlayout_00.ActMain">

<include
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/status2"></include>

<include
    android:id="@+id/lay2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/meine_vertaege"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```

**output of act_main.xml**:

[image]

Comment: try put those 2 layouts in scrollview and set weight for those 2 layouts in act_main.xml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
            <include
                android:id="@+id/lay1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1dp"
                layout="@layout/status2"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/lay2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1dp"
                layout="@layout/meine_vertaege"></include>
</LinearLayout>
```